# Put multiple paragraph tags on same line

Tags: html, css

I want the main text (hello) on the left, and the background text (loading) on the right of the screen, but vertically aligned with the main text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="load.css">
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="textContainer">
    <p class="hello">Hello</p>
    <div class="backgroundInfo">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <p class="notifText">Loading</p>
    </div>
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

(spinner and loader are css animations)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
.hello {
    float: left;
}

.notifText{
    float: right;
}

.loader {
    clear: both;   
}
```

```html
<div class="textContainer">
   <p class="hello">Hello</p>
   <div class="backgroundInfo">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
       <p class="notifText">Loading</p>
   </div>
   <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello has a font size of 200px, and i want notifText to be much less than that, any idea how i could align it to be centered with .hello?

Answer (score 0):

To make both paragraphs display on the same line, just use:

```
p{
    float: left;
}
```

Next step would be CSS width of both elements and the cointainer.